# Fix a 'Cannot read property handleClick of undefined error' (and issues related to deleting an item from the DOM)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

### Background

I'm working on a final project for school that displays a list of tv shows/programs using cards. I am trying to set up a way to delete a card. I'm getting all sorts of turned around trying to get this delete to work on my frontend. I've spent so long researching the issue that every solution I think of now seems both right and wrong.

First, there was a problem where programId was undefined which I fixed. Now I can't figure out how make make my `this` in `this.handleClick` work. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286460/redux-call-to-action-creator-returns-cannot-read-property-props-of-undefined) made me think that I might need to use bind. But I am not sure.

### Code

This is a section of my *Program.js* file, where the card is styled and props passed in to populate fields like name, network, and image. I use props.match.params because I've implemented React Router and need to access each card's data for the ternary statements inside. EDIT: [Program.js](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Program.js) is a functional component. I've included a link.

```
let handleClick = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteProgram(id)

  }

let program = props.program ? props.program : props.programs[props.match.params.id - 1]
let programId = program.id

    return(
        <Grid.Column>
          <Card onClick={(_) => this.handleClick(programId)}>
            <Image src={program ? program.image : null} wrapped ui={false} />
            <Card.Content>
              <Card.Header>{program ? program.name: null}</Card.Header>
              <Card.Meta>
                <span className='date'>{program ? program.network : null 
                </span>
              </Card.Meta>
```

Here is my *Programs.js* file, which creates each Program component. I am unsure whether I should import my `{deleteProgram}` action/function in this file where I am creating each Program, or if I need to import it directly in Program.
EDIT: [Programs.js](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Programs.js) is a functional component. I've added a link.

```
        <Grid columns='six' divided='vertically'>
          <Grid.Row >
              {props.programs.map((program) => <Program key={program.id} program={program} />)}
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
```

This is the *programsReducer* file with the case statement for deleting a program.

```
case 'DELETE_PROGRAM':
      const programs = state.programs.filter(program => program.id !== 
          action.id)
      return {programs}
```

Here is my *deleteProgram* action/function.

```
return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/programs/${id}`,{
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => dispatch({type: 'DELETE_PROGRAM', id: id}))
  }
}
```

### Recap of Questions

1. Do you know why I am getting an error that `this` in my `this.handleSubmit` is undefined?
2. Which file --Programs.js (with the .map) or Program.js (which each individual card -- should I import my `{deleteProgram}` function/action into?

### Bonus Round

If memory serves, I need to put this onClick method on the entire card. I would love to call it on a delete button I made within the card. Can someone confirm whether this is correct or not?

Thank you very much for your time! :-)

Comment: Is your handleClick function defined in your render method? Post the full code so we can help out or post a sandbox link.

Comment: can you post the whole class? im assuming your using a `function` and not the `arrow function` thats why the this is not attaching to the right scope

Comment: I'm using a functional component in both [Programs](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Programs.js) and [Program](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Program.js).

Comment: Change this.props to just props and call the function without this since it is a stateless component

Comment: @RohitKashyap I did that and am now getting a new error: `props.handleClick is not a function`

Comment: use handleClick without props. Inside handleClick, use just props.deleteProgram(id) without using this.

Comment: Since it's 404, I can only assume there is something wrong with your route. Might be an issue with your express setup assuming you are using node.js

Comment: @RohitKashyap I deleted my previous comment that mentioned the error because when I moved the onClick from my <Card> to the button element inside of it, they all went away. Thanks so much for helping me to get moving on this! *high five*

Comment: Mark it as the correct answer if it helped you so others can see this in the future. :)

Comment: @RohitKashyap How do I mark answers within a comment thread correct? I upvoted them, but I don't see a check mark to click. Ignore this comment. I just scrolled down and saw your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your code to the following:**

```
let handleClick = (id) => {
  props.deleteProgram(id)

  }

let program = props.program ? props.program : props.programs[props.match.params.id - 1]
let programId = program.id

return(
    <Grid.Column>
      <Card onClick={(_) => handleClick(programId)}>
        <Image src={program ? program.image : null} wrapped ui={false} />
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>{program ? program.name: null}</Card.Header>
          <Card.Meta>
            <span className='date'>{program ? program.network : null 
            </span>
          </Card.Meta>
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: One of the ways to bind this is in the constructor of the component.

```
this.function = this.function.bind(this);
```

Regarding Question 2: I would send the deleteCardFunction() in as a prop for each individual card. Then call it from the card with the id when you want to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a function component, not a class, you shouldn't use this there.  Just use the function name.

`<Card onClick={() => handleClick(programId)}>`

should even work without binding it in there, since you are already doing it with an arrow function in the function declaration:

`<Card onClick={handleClick(programId)}>`

I would import delete into Program.js, since it makes sense to have the delete button inside that.

Another neat trick, instead of using the ? : shorthand, you can do it even shorter, using ||, like:

`let program = props.program || props.programs[props.match.params.id - 1]`

To be able to put another onClick inside the card, you will have to stop the event from bubbling up, calling event.stopPropagation() before or inside your delete method.